# Why I need Google Analytics UTM

Tags: google-analytics, utm, utm-tracking

I can see sources of visits and other related data on my Google Analytics screen. As I read so far, UTM tracking aims to track where the users come from and some other things like what did they do on website.

But as I said, I can see these kind of things on regular Analytics scrren. So why I need UTM then?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Google recognizes some sources automatically (direct, organic, referral and to some extent SEM). However it does not automatically recognize campaign traffic.

E.g. if somebody clicks on a newsletter link in a webmailer this would be counted as referral traffic. By adding campaign parameters you could instead track this in a custom newsletter channel with e.g. one campaign name per newsletter.

Links from other websites would show up as referral, if these are your affiliates you track them as such via UTM parameters. SEM traffic is organized into campaigns by UTM parameters (or the gclid parameter from adwords autotagging, which is more common).

So if you want to know which of your marketing measures are successful you'd use utm parameters in destination urls. If you do not do marketing campaigns you do not need them.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer.